# How to add subdomains to cloudflare's network?

Tags: cloudflare

I signed up for cloudflare in order to speed up my website & protect it from attacks. But I'm unable to figure out how to add subdomains & sites installed at (directories) www.domain.com/directory to cloudflare network. Everytime I try to visit xyz.domain.com or domain.com/xyz it shows website offline/Unavailable message.

I don't know if cloudflare has crawled the subdomains or not.

P.s The website at www.domain.com works just fine. Problem is with subdomains & directories. DNS settings & everything else is good from my side.

Comment: Shouldn't you address this question to cloudflare?

Comment: [Please read this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your DNS settings are alright? Do you have any A or CNAME record pointing to your ip address, e.g.:

```
subdomain.example.org A 192.168.1.1
```

Cloudflare [states that's the only way to add a subdomain](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168756-How-do-I-add-a-subdomain-) to Cloudflare's network.

Comment: Your DNS terminology is a bit off - A records do not point at subdomains, they resolve to (ipv4) addresses.

Comment: I was a bit unclear, as English is not my primary language. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

"www.domain.com/directory" This isn't a subdomain (it is a folder on the site). A subdomain would be directory.yourdomain.com.

Glad you figured this out. In the future, if you have to add a subdomain, you can do so in your DNS settings (after you create the subdomain).